# Python socket accept in the main thread prevents quitting

Tags: python, sockets, quit

I'm playing around with sockets in python, just for the purpose of learning about them. However I am really annoyed with the following problem:

```
import socket
soc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET)
soc.bind(('localhost',8000))
soc.listen(0)
client = soc.accept()
```

While the socket is waiting for a connection, pressing ctrl-c does not quit the application.

**How can I quit the application?**

A similar issue was addressed in [these](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1148062/566639) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4090891/566639) questions, but there the `accept` method was called from a separate thread and the problem was how to make ctrl-c kill that thread. Here the `accept` method is called from the main thread.

*Edit:* I am running python 3.3.0 on Win7 64 bit.

Comment: I never had this problem. What environment is this ?

Comment: Edited to add the environment

Comment: How do you run it, from cmd ? If you make a script containing **strictly what you posted**, does `ctrl-c` work ?

Comment: I made a script containing strictly what I posted, and I tried running it both from cmd and from the python idle. Both do not respond to `ctrl-c`.

Comment: Can someone explain WHY it happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to kill the application using `ctrl-c` or any other way except for killing it through the task manager, so I wrote a workaround:

```
import socket,os
from threading import Thread

class socketListener(Thread):
    def run(self):
        soc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET)
        soc.bind(('localhost',8000))
        soc.listen(0)
        client = soc.accept()

pid = os.getpid()
sl = socketListener()
sl.start()
input('Socket is listening, press any key to abort...')
os.kill(pid,9)
```

This runs the script in a separate thread, while waiting for a keystroke in the main thread. Once the user presses a key, the entire application is killed.

Comment: Is there no better way?

Answer (score 6):

You should use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Break</kbd>. That should kill it.

Comment: I don't have `break` on my laptop keyboard, but I just found out `ctrl-F6` works in the python idle. It restarts the shell, which kills the application alright, but it has the downside of resetting all the variables. With `ctrl-c` there is an option to check the values of different variables and that helps when debugging.

Comment: Correction: restarting the shell does **not** kill the application. It keeps running in the background and I need to kill it through the task manager.

Answer (score 1):

After being myself confronted to the same problem I found a little workaround, it might not be the cleanest way but at least it works for me :

```
import socket
from select import select

#create an INET, STREAMing socket
serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

#bind the socket to localhost
serversocket.bind(('localhost', 8000))
While 1:
    serversocket.listen(5)
    ready, _, _ = select([serversocket], [], [], 1) #Timeout set to 1 seconds
    if ready:
        (clientsocket, address) = serversocket.accept()
        #Do something with client
    else:
        #Do nothing, just loop again
```

By using `select` you will wait a change on the socket fd until the end of the timeout. As I said this might not be the cleanest way but Ctrl-c will be catch at the end of the timeout.

**Portability alert:** On Unix, `select` works both with the sockets and files. On Windows, `select` works with sockets only.

Answer (score 0):

"serversocket" module provides the standard solution. I tested Control-C on Windows, it worked.

This is the link, [serversocket example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socketserver.html)

The Control-C handling is even mentioned in the comment of the code

```
# Activate the server; this will keep running until you
# interrupt the program with Ctrl-C
```

Here is the complete code from the above link:

```
import socketserver   
class MyTCPHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):   
    def handle(self):
        # self.request is the TCP socket connected to the client
        self.data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
        print("{} wrote:".format(self.client_address[0]))
        print(self.data)
        # just send back the same data, but upper-cased
        self.request.sendall(self.data.upper())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOST, PORT = "localhost", 9999
    with socketserver.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyTCPHandler) as server:
        # Activate the server; this will keep running until you
        # interrupt the program with Ctrl-C
        server.serve_forever()
```

If we wanted to re-invent the wheel, we would do a select() or poll() on the listener socket, with a timeout 0.5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

To save time of the other people searching for this topic, if you laptop keyboard does not have a `break` button, please try

```
Ctrl + Fn + F6
```

or

```
Ctrl + F6
```