# Why keyboard interrupt doesn't work in my Python script?

Tags: python, sockets, interrupt-handling, keyboardinterrupt

When I run this script from my windows10 terminal:

```
import time

try:
   while True:
      time.sleep(1)
      print('still alive')
except KeyboardInterrupt:
   print('Keyboard interruption. Goodbye')
```

and press ctrl-c : keyboard interruptpion is activate and the process ends

but when I run this script:

```
import socket

try:
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        s.bind(('127.0.0.1', 65432))        
        s.listen()
        conn, addr = s.accept()        
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('Keyboard interruption. Goodbye')
```

then crtl-c doesn't work and I need to find another way to shutdown my process.
Why is that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python socket accept in the main thread prevents quitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15189888/python-socket-accept-in-the-main-thread-prevents-quitting)

Comment: @SuperStormer, you are right my question is a duplication of the link you sent. But no, none of the suggestion there helped me. Very strange behavior of Windows or pyhton 3.7 on Windows