# How to stop server socket using ctrl+c in Python

Tags: python, sockets

When i run my server, when server is listening, there is no way to stop the server rather than closing the terminal. I tried to handle ctrl+c using KeyboardInterrupt, but it doesnt work. I can terminate the script using ctrl+break but i dont know how to handle it in my code.

Here is the code for my server:

```
import socket


try:
    listener = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    listener.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    listener.bind(('127.0.0.1', 4444))
    listener.listen(0)
    print('Listening...')
    listener.accept()
    print('Got a connection.')
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('Exiting...')
    exit()
```

How can i handle ctrl+break in my code?

Comment: you need to catch the signal and handle that with some function `signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, sigterm_handler)`

Comment: @Alex Can you please provide the code, i cant figure it out :(

Comment: It reacts to ctrl-C as expected on Linux; this looks like a problem specific to Windows: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15189888/python-socket-accept-in-the-main-thread-prevents-quitting

Comment: @VPfB Yes it is specific to Windows. I tried to use a signal for at least catching the ctrl+break interrupt but i couldn't solve the problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5308168/3962537 | Or set a relatively short timeout (a second or something like that) for the accept, running it in a loop.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If no client is waiting, `socket.accept()` hangs until a connection is made and can't be interrupted by <kbd>CTRL-C</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL-BREAK</kbd>.  Use `select.select()` to wait for a connection to be readable from the server socket along with a timeout.  The timeout will allow <kbd>CTRL-C</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL-BREAK</kbd> to be recognized.

<kbd>CTRL-C</kbd> raises `KeyboardInterrupt`, but <kbd>CTRL-BREAK</kbd> needs a signal handler.  I've set up a custom exception to be raised on the `SIGBREAK` signal below:

```py
import signal
import socket
import select

# Custom exception with same base class as KeyboardInterrupt
class CtrlBreakInterrupt(BaseException):
    pass

def handler(*args):
    raise CtrlBreakInterrupt

signal.signal(signal.SIGBREAK, handler)

# Set up server
with socket.socket() as server:
    server.bind(('', 5000))
    server.listen()
    to_read = [server]
    clients = {}  # lookup table for addresses

    try:
        while True:
            # Check for connections or data
            readable, _, _ = select.select(to_read, [], [], 0.2)
            for sock in readable:
                if sock is server:
                    client, address = sock.accept()
                    to_read.append(client)
                    clients[client] = address
                    print(f'{client}:{address}: connected')
                else:
                    data = sock.recv(4096)
                    if data:
                        print(f'{clients[sock]}: {data}')
                    else:
                        print(f'{clients[sock]}: disconnected')
                        to_read.remove(sock)
                        del clients[sock]
    except CtrlBreakInterrupt:
        print('CTRL-BREAK')
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('CTRL-C')
```

Comment: Does not work on windows. `with sock.accept()` raise exception `AttributeError: __enter__`

Comment: @wanyancan It worked if no client had connected.  I guess I hadn't tested that.  It works now whether a client is connected or not.

Answer (score -1):

something like this .

```
def handler(signum, frame):
    print 'Shutting down...'
    sys.exit(1)


signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, handler)

while True:
    clientsocket, address = listener.accept()
    clientsocket.send(bytes("hi.","utf-8"))
```